# Heterocesdastic model of mixed effects via lmer function

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I am adjusting a mixed effects model which, due to the observed heteroscedasticity, it was necessary to include an effect to accommodate it. Therefore, using the `lme` function of the `nlme` package, this was easy to be solved, see the code below:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
Model1 <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                     (Var4)+(Var5),
                    random = ~1|Var6, Data1, method="REML",
                   weights = varIdent(form=~1|Var7))
#Var6: It is a factor with several levels.
#Var7: It is a Dummy variable.
```

However, I need to readjust the model described above using the `lme4` package, that is, using the `lmer` function. It is known and many are the materials that inform some limitations existing in the `lme4`, such as, for example, modeling heteroscedasticity. What motivated me to readjust this model is the fact that I have an interest in using a specific package that in cases of mixed models it only accepts if they are adjusted through the `lmer` function. How could I resolve this situation? Below is a good part of the model adjusted using the lmer function, however, this model is not considering the effect to model the observed heteroscedasticity.

```
Model2 <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(1|Var6),
                    Data1, REML=T)
```

Regarding the choice of the random effect (Var6) and the inclusion of the effect to consider the heterogeneity by levels of the variable (Var7), these were carefully analyzed, however, I will not put here the whole procedure so as not to be an extensive post and to be more objective .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hackable. You need to add an observation-level random effect that is only applied to the group with the *larger* residual variance (you need to know this in advance!), via `(0+dummy(Var7,"1")|obs)`; this has the effect of multiplying each observation-level random effect value by 1 if the observation is in group "1" of `Var7`, 0 otherwise. You also need to use `lmerControl()` to override a few checks that `lmer` does to try to make sure you are not adding redundant random effects.

```r
Data1$obs <- factor(seq(nrow(Data1)))
Model2 <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                   (Var4)+(Var5) + (1|Var6) +
                   (0+dummy(Var7,"1")|obs),
               Data1, REML=TRUE,
               control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore",
                                   check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))

all.equal(REMLcrit(Model2), c(-2*logLik(Model1))) ## TRUE
all.equal(fixef(Model1), fixef(Model2), tolerance=1e-7)
```

---

If you want to use this model with `hnp` you need to work around the fact that `hnp` doesn't pass the `lmerControl` option properly.

```r
library(hnp)
d <- function(obj) resid(obj, type="pearson")
s <- function(n, obj) simulate(obj)[[1]]
f <- function(y.) refit(Model2, y.)

hnp(Model2, newclass=TRUE, diagfun=d, simfun=s, fitfun=f)
```

You might also be interested in the [DHARMa package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html), which does similar simulation-based diagnostics.

[image: half-normal plot]

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you very much for your feedback. However, when I take the model presented by you and try to plot the half-normal plot using the ````hnp```` function of the ````hnp```` package for diagnostic analysis, the following message appears: ````Erro: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: obs)````. What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Well, I don't know what the `hnp` function is doing.  Presumably it's trying to re-run the model, and failing to pass the `lmerControl` specification ... ?

Comment: Probably yes, in this situation is there any way that I can make this graph taking advantage of the help you provided regarding the adjustment in ````lmer````? I really liked your answer, however, I need to perform the half-normal plot of this model, but for this, the function only works if a mixed effects model is adjusted using ````lmer````, due to this I would like to use your answer .